# Compiling Typescript to NodeJs: es6 types issues

Tags: node.js, typescript, npm

I think i'm missing something with the typescript 2 type system when used with nodejs.

---

Here is the situation:

- Compiling a small nodejs express server written in typescript to plain **es5** in order to be run under node **6.10.0** (**target: es5** in tsconfig.json).
- In my package.json, i installed **@types/node** (**7.0.3**) to get node's type informations.

When installing my project using npm (v3.10.10) and then compiling it with typescript (v2.1.5) i get a bunch or errors related to 'Iterable' and 'Iterator' symbol, (which are es6 symbols).

So from what i understand, **@types/node** use es6 types out of the box, assuming they are already availables.

In order to have the es6 types (Iterator, Iterable and so on) it seams that there is two solutions:

1. Add the **core-js** package.
2. **Target es6 instead of es5** in tsconfig.json which will force typescript to use it's *lib/lib.es2015.*.d.ts* definitions files.

---

In my opinion, the second approach is better.

Is this the official way to go when compiling ts to node ?
ie: targeting es6 in tsconfig ?

How can i be sure that the underlying node engine will effectively support those es6 features ? What if i'm using an old nodejs version without es6 support ?

I'd be glad to discuss to clearly understand the underlying mechanisms !

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Since node doesn't support completely all es6 features  yet see : [node green](http://node.green/),

it's better to target es5 and install core-js types :

```
npm install @types/core-js
```

Comment: I find that NodeJS support ES6 (with the harmony flag set) has been really good for quite some time. Actually 6.10.0 is the LTS version and it does support most if not all ES6 features. It is reasonable to impose that no  version older that the LTS is used. In short, I would go for ES6 now